# getfolderpath & Program Data

Tags: powershell

I have been successfully using `[environment]::getfolderpath("ProgramFiles")` to get the path to program Files, but now I have a need to also access Program Data, and it looks from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration like ProgramData is not available with this method. Is that true, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Would just using `$env:ProgramData` work?

Comment: Well, damn, thats a better way to do the Program Files stuff too! This is rather old code, so I am guessing I got it from someone with a C# background who was using the hard way. And, that's why we refactor! ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way is to use `$env:ProgramData` as BenH already pointed out in your question comments.

Using the .net Specialfolder, you would have needed to use the **CommonApplicationData**

Instead of using a string though such as your initial example:

`[Environment]::GetFolderPath('CommonApplicationData')`

I'd suggest using the enumeration as you will get the possible enumeration values directly into the intellisense while developping.

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath([System.Environment+SpecialFolder]::CommonApplicationData)
```

Finally, because you knew the path you were looking for but not the corresponding variable, you could have listed them all neatly using something like:

```
$SpecialFolders = New-Object -TypeName psobject
[Environment+SpecialFolder]::GetNames([Environment+SpecialFolder]) | sort | 
foreach {Add-Member -InputObject $SpecialFolders -Type NoteProperty  -Name 
($_) -Value ([Environment]::GetFolderPath($_)) }


$SpecialFolders | fl
```

Using that snippet, you could have determined that c:\programdata was a special folder path belonging to CommonApplicationData.

The enumeration can still be handy if a specified folder is not in the **$env** scope (example: My documents special folder).

Answer (score 14):

**$env:** to access environmental variables

```
$env:ProgramData
```